# Ryanair check-in shows my date of birth 10 days wrong

Tags: check-in, ryanair

I tried to check in for my flight on Ryanair's website, but it was too early. Now when I try again, it shows my date of birth 10 days wrong and I cannot change it.  (No, it is not swapping the month and date. The month and year are correct.)

This tripadvisor thread has over [80 replies about people with the same problem](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k11267887-o60-Ryanair_wrong_birthdate-Air_Travel.html), but nobody has a clear solution.  Ryanair no longer has any way to contact them on their website other than calling by phone for which they charge a lot of money.

What I already tried:

- Clearing my cache
- Use an incognito window in Google Chrome version 76
- Log into the Ryanair website and enter my date of birth into my profile. The profile shows my correct date of birth, but it's still wrong on the check-in screen.

I don't want to pay extra money to solve this problem. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Wait until you get to the airport and ask the check-in staff or Ryanair desk?

Comment: One option you don’t mention is the Ryanair app - I don’t have it as I refuse to fly Ryanair on principle, but it’s worth a try to see if it lets you correct the error? Failing that, I’d take screenshots of your profile showing the correct date and the check in screen showing the wrong one with me to the airport in case the problem causes any issues.

Comment: There are several people on the thread saying they just left the incorrect date in place, and were able to travel without any problems since it never gets checked.   That's the closest thing to a "clear solution" I saw.

Comment: I wonder where they got the info from. Not familiar with the Ryanair booking or check-in progress, but do they ask for info about your passport or ID card by any chance? Could that have been entered incorrectly?

Answer (score 7):

I just direct messaged them on twitter with a short description of what you said above and they said they can change it for you for free. They have helped me with similar issues before and the team is always great, you will be able to direct message them on @ryanair and get it sorted in no time!

A copy of what we said:

> 1:00 PM, **ME**:  Hi, I tried to check in for my flight online and it is showing my date
>   of birth as an incorrect date. (It is wrong by only 10 days) Is there
>   a way for me to change this online? I have tried on the website but it
>   won't let me edit it. The date of birth on my profile is
>   correct
>
> 1:17 PM, **RYANAIR**:  Hi Ucie, in order to check this for you and access
>   your booking, could you please type this information for us for a
>   security check:
>
> - Type “Booking Reference” and include 6 digit reference code
> - Full name of the passengers and date of birth
> - Route, date and time
> - Email entered in the booking
> - 4 last digits of the credit card which was used to pay for the booking
>
> Thanks, 
>   Ana
>
> 1:17 PM, **ME**:  Are you asking as you would be able to change it for me?
>
> 1:30 PM, **RYANAIR**:  Yes, we can change it without any additional cost, Alisofi

Comment: Just a note, send it as a direct message and not a tweet. You don't want that information to be public

Comment: Agreed @paullb Ryanair themselves would ask you to DM them about it too as they wouldn't want the data public

Comment: The TripAdvisor thread cited in the question has lots of people saying they talked to RyanAir via chat or other means, and the rep claimed to have fixed the error, but when they went back and checked it was still wrong.  So without someone actually trying it, I wouldn't be convinced that this solution actually works.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, I went ahead and checked in online even though it wouldn't let me correct my date of birth.  Then I went a bit early to the airport in case it might take time to fix it. I asked the agent at check-in and he confirmed it was wrong in the system and directed me to the customer service desk. The agent there fixed it easily. (Or at least they said they did.)

So, all sorted with only about 15 minutes extra waiting in line for customer service.

(Traveller also made a good suggestion to bring screenshots to the airport, but I didn't see the comment in time to do so.  Uciebila's suggestion to send a DM on twitter is also a good idea although it would require me to set up a twitter account.. Thanks all!)